# WCF web.config: Allowing SOAP headers in BasicHttpBinding over HTTP (not HTTPS)

Tags: c#, rest, wcf, soap, web-config

I do NOT have HTTPS (SSL) on my sub-domain, so as such HTTPS anything is out, just HTTP.

I have one Operation in my WCF service, which requires SOAP, at least according to the error messages, as the return type is complex.

```
[OperationContract(IsOneWay = false)]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
    FileDownloadReturnMessage DownloadFile(FileDownloadMessage request);
```

I had to change my Binding Security to `None`, as `Transport` requires HTTPS, at least from the error messages that I received; the same for `WsHttpBinding`, hence now `basicHttpBinding`. The web.config has 3 bindings at the moment: `webHttpBinding`, `basicHttpBinding`, and `mex`.

The problem is that SOAP and HTTP appear incompatible. Here is the error message that I see, when I stick the URL into a Google Chrome browser:

> [InvalidOperationException: Operation 'DownloadFile' in contract 'ICloudService' uses a MessageContract that has SOAP headers. SOAP headers are not supported by the None MessageVersion.]

Here is the URI:

```
http://mycloud.thedomain.com/Communication/CloudService.svc/AddressWs
```

The following URI throws the same error.

```
http://mycloud.thedomain.com/Communication/CloudService.svc/AddressWeb
```

Here is the `web.config`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.2"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:1659;1699;1701"/>
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+"/>
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <services>
            <service name="MyCloud.Communication.CloudService" behaviorConfiguration="BehaviorMyCloudService">
                <endpoint address="/AddressWeb"
                                    binding="webHttpBinding"
                                    bindingConfiguration="EndpointBindingMyCloudService"
                                    contract="MyCloud.Communication.ICloudService"
                                    behaviorConfiguration="endpointBehaviorWeb"
                                    >
                    </endpoint>
                <endpoint address="/AddressWs"
                                    binding="basicHttpBinding"
                                    bindingConfiguration="EndpointBindingMyCloudService"
                                    contract="MyCloud.Communication.ICloudService"
                                    behaviorConfiguration="endpointBehaviorWs"
                                    >
                </endpoint>
                <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
                <host>
                    <baseAddresses>
                        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:80/"/>
                    </baseAddresses>
                </host>
            </service>
        </services>
        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="BehaviorMyCloudService">
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="false" />
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
                    <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
                    <useRequestHeadersForMetadataAddress>
                        <defaultPorts>
                            <add scheme="http" port="80" />
                        </defaultPorts>
                    </useRequestHeadersForMetadataAddress>
                </behavior>
                <behavior name="">
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="false" />
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
            <endpointBehaviors>
                <behavior name="endpointBehaviorWeb">
                    <webHttp defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Xml" />
                </behavior>
                <behavior name="endpointBehaviorWs">
                    <webHttp defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Xml" />
                </behavior>
            </endpointBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <protocolMapping>
            <add scheme="http" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="EndpointBindingMyCloudService" />
            <add scheme="https" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="EndpointBindingMyCloudService" />
        </protocolMapping>
        <bindings>
            <webHttpBinding>
                <binding
                    name="EndpointBindingMyCloudService"
                    allowCookies="false"
                    closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                    openTimeout="00:01:00"
                    receiveTimeout="00:10:00"
                    sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                    maxBufferPoolSize="524288"
                    maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
                    useDefaultWebProxy="true"
                    >
                    <security mode="None">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"></transport>
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </webHttpBinding>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding
                    name="EndpointBindingMyCloudService"
                    allowCookies="false"
                    closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                    openTimeout="00:01:00"
                    receiveTimeout="00:10:00"
                    sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                    maxBufferPoolSize="524288"
                    maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
                    useDefaultWebProxy="true"
                    >
                    <security mode="None">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"></transport>
                        </security>
                </binding>
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true">
            <baseAddressPrefixFilters>
                <add prefix="http://localhost:80"/>
            </baseAddressPrefixFilters>
        </serviceHostingEnvironment>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

My C# code throws an annoying error:

> ex = {"The requested service, 'http://mycloud.thedomain.com/Communication/CloudService.svc/AddressWs' could not be activated. See the server's diagnostic trace logs for more information."}

I get better mileage sticking the URL in a Chrome browser.

What changes do I need to make to my `web.config` to get complex return values and still use HTTP?

Comment: The service is listening at localhost port 80. You are connecting to mycloud.thedomain.com.  Are they the same?

Comment: @jdweng My web hosting company directed me to use port 80. I uploaded the site, `web.config` shown above, connecting to the site from my desktop using a C# WinForms desktop application and separately my Google Chrome browser. If I understand your question, yes. The sub-domain, mycloud.thedomain.com, from the WCF web service perspective is `localhost`. My desktop is not, of course.

Comment: If you can connect using Google Chrome then use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and capture good connection.  Then compare to bad connection.  Look at the headers in initial request.  Make the c# application headers look like the working connection.

Comment: @jdweng That is the point. I CANNOT connect either way. I gave the browser error and C# error. Both yielded errors. SOAP appears to require SSL or security = transport, but HTTP (no SSL) requires security = None, a catch 22, hence my question. It should be possible to do both. I just do not know how.

Comment: Please take a look at the following blog.
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/carlosfigueira/2008/04/17/wcf-raw-programming-model-web-receiving-arbitrary-data/
In my opinion, you can try to break the contract down into two separate service contract. One is marked restful, and the other is marked soap.
In addition, why not try to use the data contract type as the return type?

Comment: When a client connects to a server there is a negotiation that takes place between headers on the server and headers in the request to get a common mode of operation.  If a server only supports secure mode, then the server will override the client settings of non-secure.